# Order by inside subquery

Tags: sql-server

Suppose that i select into a temptable as follow by performing grouping from an existing table, and this is current temptable value:

```
Title Count
-------------
Sr.   11
Mrs.  2
Sra.  3
Ms.   415
Mr.   578
```

What I want to achieve is a comma separated value for title as follow, which is **order by count**

```
[Mrs.], [Sra.], [Sr.], [Ms.], [Mr.]
```

However, currently i can only able to achieve a comma separated value as follow, which is the default ordering in #temptable

```
[Sr.], [Mrs.], [Sra.], [Ms.], [Mr.]
```

Below is my code. How could i achieve what i wanted? 
Note: I don't assume nor expect the sequence is already in order when inserting into the #temptable

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(Title)
FROM
   (
    SELECT Title FROM #tempTable1
   ) AS P
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in this way:

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max);

SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(Title)
                      FROM tempTable1
                      ORDER BY [Count]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @Columns;
```

> ```
> | (No column name)                     |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> |  [Mrs.], [Sra.], [Sr.], [Ms.], [Mr.] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a81f5a2065508c9e82b5bcc484beba4)*

Alternatively and depending on your SQL-Server version you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max);

SELECT
    STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Title), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Count])
FROM
    tempTable1;

SELECT @Columns;
```

Comment: Adding that `XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG` with `ORDER BY` are the correct methods for aggregate string concatenation. `TOP 100 PERCENT` method will keep the parser happy but will not guarantee ordering or proper behavior, depending on the execution plan.

Comment: @DanGuzman edited.